# Print std::pair representing points using iterators

Tags: c++

I am programming in C++. I have a pair representing points:

```
typedef pair<int,int> point;
```

and I declare an array of points:

```
point P[];
set <point> mySet;
```

`mySet` contains the elements stored in `P[]`.

I want to show the contents of `mySet` using an iterator.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Bonjour. Ceci est un site uniquement anglais. Donc traduisez votre question en anglais, s'il vous plait. Si jamais vous avez besoin de l'aide pour ca, n'hésitez pas nous le demander.

Comment: Vad är det du försöker säga?

Comment: @CaptainObvlious Non comprende.

Comment: @H2CO3 I have no idea what it says either. It's Swedish or something meatballish.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious Ah. Well done.

Answer (score 0):

> MySet contains the elements stored in P [] I want to display the
>   contents of MySet using an iterator. How should I proceed to do this.

Well, if we trust google translate then I would say:

```
for ( auto & point : MySet ) { /** show (* point ) **/ }
```

or,

```
for ( auto itpoint= MySet.begin() ; ( itpoint != MySet.end() ) ; ++ itpoint )
{
  /** show ( * itpoint ) **/
}
```

Comment: Surprisingly, Google Translate did pretty well this time.

Comment: std::begin(MySet) and std::end(MySet) can be used, too.

Comment: I try that solution and a have these errors:  1) ISO C++ forbids declaration of `itpoint' with no type. 2)  cannot convert `std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<std::pair<int, int> >' to `int' in initialization . 3)  cannot convert `std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<std::pair<int, int> >' to `int' in initialization

Answer (score 0):

To get a corresponding iterator simply do `set<point>::interator it;`. Then you can use the members `begin()` and `end()`, e.g.

```
for (it = mySet.begin(); it != mySet.end(); ++it)
{
    /* code */
}
```

You can acces the elements behind the iterator with `it->first` and `it->second`.

With C++11 you can also use `auto`/foreach:

```
for (auto& elem : mySet)
{
    /* code */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the simplest way is to use the range-based for statement:

```
for ( auto p : mySet )
{
   std::cout << "( " << p.first << ", " << p.second << " )" << std::endl;
}
```